# C# Suppressed warnings appearing in Azure Build Pipelines

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, suppress-warnings, stylecop

I've added **Stylecop.Analyzers** nuget package in my .Net Core project, I have suppressed the following warnings on my project:

[image]

After having 0 errors and 0 warnings in my visual studio locally, my azure build pipeline is still displaying those warnings, here's one of them:

> ##[warning]CSC(0,0): Warning SA0001: XML comment analysis is disabled due to project configuration
> [D:\a\1\s\FooRoot\Services\FooService\FooProjectService.csproj]

Currently it is not failing the build pipelines but I wanted to have a warning-free build pipeline

**EDIT:** My pipeline looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: what is your azure build pipeline YAML looks like ?

Comment: Added pic of my .net core dotnet build

Comment: refer my answer you can include in the arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i assume you are using `dotnet build` in Azure pipeline
and you can suppress warning with `-nowarn` options

in you case something like that
`dotnet build -nowarn:SA1636`

Comment: The -nowarn:SA1636 -nowarn:MSB3052 -nowarn:SA0001 in the Arguments field worked! Thanks :)

Comment: If someone uses task **VSBuild@1** in the pipeline, then add the _nowarn_ argument by this code line: `msbuildArgs: '-nowarn:xxx'` (_xxx_ is your warning code) The line has to be added into the _inputs_ section of the task. . . . . . If someone uses the task **MSBuild@1**, then the code line is similar, but not equal: `msbuildArguments: '-nowarn:xxx'` . . . . . Important: Don't use plain numbers as you can do in the project settings. (e.g. use `CS1591` instead of just `1591` for suppressing the _Missing XML comment_ warning)